# SQLException when executing a callablestatement

Tags: java, plsql, package, procedure, callable-statement

I am trying to call a Procedure from a package from my java application but receive an error. The code is set up like so...

------Java-----

```
Connection = conn;
String call_code="{? = call MY_PROCEDURE.Process_vale(?,?,?)}";
CallableStatement Process_cs=conn.prepareCall(call_code);

String bValue= "12345";
Process_cs.setString(1, bValue);
Process_cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
Process_cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
Process_cs.execute();
```

---

The Procedure is setup like:

```
PROCEDURE Process_value (bValue VARCHAR2, PN_CD OUT NUMBER, PN_MSG OUT VARCHAR2).....
```

The Error I see is:

java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 4

I am curious as to why it mentions an index of 4, when the Procedure only has 3 parameters, I believe I am missing a critical fact here.

Comment: You appear to have one out parameter you aren't registering; the result `? =`

Answer (score 0):

You have done some serious mistakes here. First Since you are calling a procedure you wont get any return value, only functions can have return values. So you have to call the procedure as follows.

```
String call_code="{call MY_PROCEDURE.Process_vale(?,?,?)}";
```

You could be successfully execute this if your procedure first parameter is IN type and other two parameters are OUT type.